# Java method call with parameter that uses stream api

Tags: java, methods, parameters, stream

I am just trying to call a method with one parameter which is a list from stream api call:

```
submit(animals.stream().filter(a -> !invalidNames.contains(a.getName()) && a.getClassification().contains("Test")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

And the method is like:

```
protected void submit(List<Animal> animals)
```

This is just a made-up code to illustrate what I am trying to do.

`animals` only has one element in there and the parameter passed to `submit` should be an empty collection but it's not.

When I stopped at the call to `submit` and evaluated the stream api call in Intellij

`animals.stream().filter(a -> !invalidNames.contains(a.getName()) && a.getClassification().contains("Test")).collect(Collectors.toList()`

it gave empty ArrayList which is expected but when the actual code runs into `submit` the parameter is not an empty list.

I suspect it is to do with the evaluation order or the stream operations finishes after the call to `submit` and this is a bad practise (using stream api during method call) ?

Comment: "*I suspect it is to do with the evaluation order or the stream operations finishes after the call to `submit`*" - No. The stream-operation is a blocking operation, and in Java, all parameters are evaluated before the method is called.

Comment: @Turing85 I thought the same hence why the code was like that but ... really strange case

Comment: More specifically, Streams consist of intermediate and terminal operations. Terminal operations (ex: 'collect') will block until processing is complete while intermediate operations tweak how the stream will process elements when a terminal operation is called. Without a sample input it will be difficult to provide assistance. Maybe the list created from the Stream is not actually empty?

Comment: @mike1234569 _"Without a sample input it will be difficult to provide assistance."_ agree. Was just trying to see if this is something obvious that I missed. Well like I mentioned, I evaluated the stream collect right before calling into the method and it is empty. I will try to create a full example.

Comment: One more example of streams making debugging a nightmare. Good old `for` loops are much more debugging-friendly.

Comment: Your description of what you’re doing can’t really be analyzed for mistakes, but code can be.  Edit your question and include a [mre].  Something we can compile and run so we can see your problem in action.

Comment: @VGR - I will try to create one but either way, thank you for looking into it. Really appreciated.